# ASP.NET Core Web API connection is not secure

Tags: ssl, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, and when I open Swagger, it says that the connection is secure. But when I try to open an endpoint (`GET`) in the browser and outside of swagger, I get error 401 (that's right), but it says that the application is not secure.

I have configured in `Program.cs` to use `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and I have tried several approaches but it still says that the connection is not secure.

Swagger:

[image: SWAGGER]

Browser:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the details program.cs setting to us to check? Which browser you have used? Could you please translate the error message to English?